# How can I integrate "chat" into an ASP.NET MVC site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, chat, livechat, chatroom

I'd like to integrate chat into my site and am open to a solution like this site's, but am open to others if they exist.

What chat sites do you know of that can integrate into an MVC site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one [project on CodePlex](http://whiteboardchat.codeplex.com/) you might take a look at.

Comment: You are not mentioning the project name, just a link that is currently broken.

Answer (score 4):

I have used both the [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/) JavaScript and Silverlight API's.
In your case you could use the JavaScript API from an MVC app.
Creating chat with WebSync is really easy and works very well. WebSync is a highly scalable HTTP Comet/Reverse Ajax server. They even offer a offer a hosted service. It has a cost if you need to support more than 10 concurrent users.